# jquery mobile with phonegap 404 ajax error. But working fine in Firefox, IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

local Xml file(excel.xml) is there in the xml folder in the root folder. Its working fine in Firefox, IE. but not working in Android 4.0. I am using phonegap to build. Please assist.

```
   function LoadDB(isToolTip) {
       $.support.cors = true;
       $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

       QuestionDB = new Array();
       $.ajax({
           url: 'xml/EXCEL.xml',
           dataType: 'xml',
           type: 'GET'

       }).done(function (data) {
           QuestionDB = $(data).find('Record');
           // alert(QuestionDB.length + " : " + data)
           if (isToolTip)
               showTip();
       }).fail(function (jqXHR, txtStatus, trownError) {
           alert("failed : " + txtStatus);
           alert(jqXHR.status);
           alert(trownError);
           alert(jqXHR.responseText);
       })
   }
```

Comment: The file name is "excel.xml" or "EXCEL.xml"?

Comment: Its EXCEL.xml. Does letter case makes any difference?

Comment: Yes, in certain cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502712/isnt-android-file-exists-case-sensitive

Comment: I never think of it . It was .XML instead of .xml which created the problem. Thanks

Comment: Answer your question and mark it as the right answer. That way it won't show up in the unanswered category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android system is case sensitive on file names.
 It was .XML instead of .xml which created the problem. Thanks

Comment: Bhanu, if you can, please mark your question as answered. That'll bring closure to your question.

Comment: How can I mark this as answered, I didn't find the option.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!